# How does ILogger logs to Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

In an Azure Function, when you enable telemetry to Application Insight and fire a (for example) `logger.LogInformation` call (where `logger` is an `ILogger` instance), does it send it to the Application Insight instance asynchronously (ie non-blocking), synchronously (blocking), or through a local log that gets drained asynchronously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Generally*, the logger would be hooked up to turn log calls into the various `trackMessage` or related calls in the Application Insights SDK.  those messages get batched up in the AI side, and then sent after a threshold count of messages has been met, or after a certain amount of time has elapsed.  the calls into application insights are all non-blocking, and will not throw exceptions (you don't want telemetry to negatively affect your real app!)

the c# sdks that azure functions would use would be here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/

I said *generally* at the top, because all this depends on how the SDK is configured, and that would be up to the Azure functions underlying code.  The GitHub with their info is here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions, and they have a specific wiki set up with AI info as well, here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights

Answer (score 2):

This appears the be the relevant code for specifically *how* data is sent to Application Insights:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/tree/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel

The `ILogger` wraps a `TelemetryClient`, which sends data to an `ITelemetryChannel`.

The `InMemoryTelemetryChannel` contains the logic for how data is pooled and sent to Application Insights.  As John mentioned, the channel uses a "buffer" for storing data that hasn't been sent.  The buffer is flushed and the data sent asynchronously to Azure Portal when either the buffer is full or at a specific time internal (30 seconds).